# acess file in raw folder in android by calling them from their names

Tags: android

My code is below:
I am not able to use a string in the file name. Any suggestions? 
If i use R.raw.anyString , it shows error

```
tv3.setText(readTxt());
}

private String readTxt(){
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filname);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Its says create Stringname file in raw folder

Comment: I have actually 10 files with name b1c1d1,b1c1d2.........b1c1d10 in res folder.I have set spiner with days 1-10.when day 1 selected file b1c1d1 shold be open and so on. I used any String say file and entered data b1c1d+p(where p is set to position+1 of spineer item selected).I used this InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file); But getting error that create file in raw folder

Answer (score 0):

This code works great for me:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(ApplicationContext.get()
            .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.countries));
```

i use it to open XML file and parse it later on i my code.